# Keyboard layout editor that works on Lion

Tags: macos, keyboard, customization

So far I've been using Ukulele for editing my keyboard layout (I assigned some shortcuts to Alt+key and changed a few others). Unfortunately, after upgrading to Lion, it's broken.

The point is, Lion changed behavior of pressed keys -- they don't repeat, apart from punctuation that does.

But I can't fix it, since Ukelele apparently uses some PPC program.

Is there any other keyboard layout editor for Mac?

Comment: I maybe able to recommend an build-in fix if only I knew what your trying to accomplish

Comment: Well, I didn't like characters that were assigned as Alt+letter, characters on the key on the left from 1 (I wanted it to be ` and ~), layout of keys on keypad (it was =/*-+ and I wanted it to be /*-+=) and decimal point key on keypad (it was . and it should be ,). So I cloned "polish pro" keyboard layout and made changes I wanted. Now, in Lion when you press and hold a letter, you see all versions of this letter with different diacritic marks. I don't see it, on my changed layout. So, I wanted to clone default keyboard layout once again and made my changes to it once again, but I can't.

Comment: Ukelele should work just fine on 10.7. Lion's press-and-hold behavior shouldn't depend on the keyboard layout or affect Ukelele. If you just want to disable the popovers, `defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`.

Answer (score 1):

I use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/), it works on Lion. It's a preference pane.

Comment: thanks, but Ukulele now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A possible alternative is

http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=keylayoutmaker

but I have never tried to use it myself